# Is there an RSS reader for Firefox that DOESN'T use legacy tech?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, rss

With the advent of Firefox 57 looming, I have gone on a mission to make all my addons Firefox 57 compatible. So far, I have been largely successful, with only two addons left; LastPass, my password manager, and Brief, my RSS reader.

The former has an update coming, so I'm not worried, but the latter I wish to replace. I've been looking for addons in the Addons Gallery, but I can't find anything that doesn't use legacy tech. So does anyone know of something?

I don't want an RSS application, because RSS is a web thing, and I like to keep my web stuff in one place.

Comment: Sorry. I asked here because I answered a similar question, which actually got an upvote or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [FeedBro](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/feedbroreader/) extension.